# In Codeigniter : How to get url if i clicked on the fetched data from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I get this data through one controller in a list in my view files,and  i also want to show in every page a different meta title. How it is Possible ?
  **View**

```
<?php   
      $data = "";
             foreach($items_data as $row){

                    $data .=  '<li class="list-group-item">

                                <a href="'.base_url("hotels/ls/".$row->item_id).'">'.$row->item_name.'<span class="fa fa-angle-double-right pull-right" style=""></span>

                            </li>';

                } 
                echo $data;
                ?>
```

Suppose i got four items like

- Books
- Pens
- Computers

All of my items are showing these urls which is pretty good.

- www.xyz.com/1
- www.xyz.com/2
- www.xyz.com/3

But i want to show my item names in every url. along with different meta tag title name.
Now when i click on any listed items my url will show something like these
This is possible or not , Because above list are getting from database.

- www.xyz.com/computers
- www.xyz.com/Books
- www.xyz.com/Pens

Here is my controller which is fetching data from database.
**Controller**

```
function index() {
            $data['items_data'] = $this->Visa_mdl->get_items_name();
            $data['title']  = "Hotels";
            $this->load->view('include/header');
            $this->load->view('hotels/visa',$data);
            $this->load->view('include/footer');
        }
```

This Controller is Linked to other Pages.

```
function ls($item_name = NULL) {

            $data['title']  = "Company Lists";
            $result = $this->Visa_mdl->get_items_company_list($item_name);
            $result1 = $this->Visa_mdl->get_items_name_in_dash($item_name);


             $data['items_data'] = $this->Visa_mdl->get_items_name();
            // $data['items_company_data'] = $this->Visa_mdl->get_items_company_list($id);
            $this->load->view('include/header',$data);
            $this->load->view('hotels/dashboard',$data);
            $this->load->view('include/footer');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
<a href="'.base_url("hotels/ls/".$row->item_id).'">'.$row->item_name.'<span class="fa fa-angle-double-right pull-right" style=""></span>
```

try

```
<a href="'.base_url("hotels/ls/".$row->item_name).'">'.$row->item_name.'<span class="fa fa-angle-double-right pull-right" style=""></span>
```

and try again.

In your code you have passed `$row->item_id` which shows item id in url, instead of that pass `$row->item_name` then it will show item name in url.

Comment: Thank you ..its working .. But  Sorry i did not mention there for what title i want to show . i want to show meta tag  title description in every items pages.is  meta tag is possible  or not

Comment: I think you have to implement ```slug``` for your pages, and save meta description, tags in your database, when your url hits, you can get the data using slug and load it in your view.

Comment: Yes, it is possible pass that value instead of `$row->item_name`

Comment: Hey @MayankPandeyz  as i wanted to get the name of my item in my url , i get that, But Problem is if my items contains white spaces then white space converted into %20, and also my other pages are linked to these item name , So my linked pages are not getting data for further pages.

Comment: @vishalkumar convert your all `$row->item_name` of table to **slug string** and save it at the same table with **slug field** and use it as `$row->slug` in anchor tag